# Strapi Admin Panel Customise

Tags: node.js, npm, strapi

In Strapi, I have two content types `Book` and `Author`, both have relation of `one-to-one`.
In admin panel content manager, when I add new book, it shows all authors in drop down to choose, if I mark any author as `Draft` then drafted author is also appearing in drop down to choose.

Here I want to not see drafted author in this drop down.

Only published author should be available to choose in this drop down.

How can I achieve this.

here is image for better explanation.

[image]

in above image red marked Author should not appear in this list.